# How can I move database from azure sql server to virtual machine?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

I'm having windows azure. I've two virtual machine setup in azure and both virtual machine has  sites. I've database on azure sql server . I just want to move azure sql server database to virtual machine's sql server.

How can I move database from azure sql server to virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also export you Azure SQL Database as BACPACK file, move it to your VM and import BACKPACK into on-prem database. This process is easier and has less than exporting via Data Export.

Here is an article how to export/import BACKPACK files: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/backup-and-restore-your-sql-azure-database-using-powershell/

Not much of GUI explained there, but the first 2 scereenshots show you how to get to exporting  and importing menus.

I recommend to practice on non-production DBs first, before you go ahead with your critical data.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this link, this will describe step by step process

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/17/10014014.aspx